# Disable entire week based on date selected on datapicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, datepicker

I have a `.datepicker()` created using jQuery UI, I now want to do so:

1. Disable all weekends and holidays,
2. Disable the entire week once user select a day in a week. Say users select Tuesday, 09/23/2014, then the datepicker should disable Monday, 09/22/2014 -- Sunday, 09/28/2014.

I was thinking about `beforeShowDay` and `onSelect` function, but I don't know how to combine my requirement together.

A little code might help:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "/painstorder/jquery-ui/images/calendar.gif",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    minDate: "dateToday",
    maxDate: new Date(2016, 2, 6),     
    buttonText: "Select date",
    dateFormat: "DD, d MM, yy",
    beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends
});
```

Comment: You got the right thinking but what have you tried?
You can create a function that checks the selected dates and returns true/false on `beforeShowDay`.
This will help you to get your started: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay
https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/5ddc7cd4d325a78e6dae3b7fbdc6313294a6d637/ui/datepicker.js#L1072

Comment: You want to disable the whole week afterwards on the same datepicker? So when the user wants to change the date on the same datepicker, he will not be able to select those dates (previously disabled)???

Comment: @BojanPetkovski  Good point. But just say what if I want to do that? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Here you are a working example http://jsfiddle.net/L25d7Lzy/1/

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    minDate: "dateToday",
    maxDate: new Date(2016, 2, 6),     
    buttonText: "Select date",
    dateFormat: "DD, d MM, yy",

    beforeShow: function () {
        if ($('#datepicker').val()) {
            var thedate = new Date($('#datepicker').val());
            var minDate = new Date(thedate.setDate(thedate.getDate() + 7));
            $('#datepicker').datepicker("option", "minDate", minDate);
        }
    },
    beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
});
```

You can modify it to your needs :)

Comment: Thanks! But I want to disable that week the selected date is in. That tricks me.